# Firefox garbage collection and RAM/memory cleanup

Tags: firefox, memory, terminal, python, memory-limit

Firefox has a feature to do garbage collection and memory cleanup: On the `about:memory` page, `Free memory > GC/CC/Minimize memory usage`. Is it possible to trigger them externally, e.g. via a terminal command or a Python script?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but the methods are in view-source:chrome://global/content/aboutMemory.js . E.G. function doGC(), which calls Cu.forceGC() .See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.forceGC for documatation. **N.B** " garbage collection is a very expensive operation"

Comment: Looks interesting, maybe, but I'm not really sure how to use this information... Regarding garbage collection, the features in `about:memory` are pretty quick and seem to take much less than a second

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to talk directly to the Firefox process via terminal, or maybe even start Firefox as a process inside Python and control it from there